# View v0, d0 registers in Cutter (ARM64)

Tags: radare2, arm64

When reversing an ARM64 binary in Cutter 2.1, I wanted to emulate certain instructions and view the values that were computed. Cutter's emulation showed the x0-x31 registers but how do I view the v0.xb, d0 registers etc and the values they hold?